# Different Login View in Different SubDomain

Tags: laravel-5

I would like to have different login view for different subdomain.

My system has 2 modules for login.
-Member: www.example.com
-Agent: agent.example.com

I would like to implement 2 different login layout also different flow but using same users table.
-Member: www.example.com/login
-Agent: agent.example.com/login

inside my `routes/web.php`

`Route::domain('agent.example.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'AgentController@showLoginForm')->name('agent.login');
});`

However, it still show my member login screen.

But if I changed to

`Route::domain('agent.example.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/agent-login', 'AgentController@showLoginForm')->name('agent.login');
});`

It display the correct controller and view.

I already added the Route::domain to filter up. But how come Laravel still pick up the original `login` route?

How do I separated it? I prefer to have agent.example.com/login instead of  agent.example.com/agent-login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because I am using acacha/adminlte-laravel packages. It has the login route included in the package.

Laravel route is organized based on priority of matching. So you want your route match first, you have to put in on the top.

And due to acacha/adminlte-laravelset the Auth::route inside the package. So I can't manually set the route priority in web.php.

What you have to do is remove the Auth::route in vendor. Fork your own repo. and do the customization.